# Accessing another script variable, but can not changing In-Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new in Unity. I've followed a tutorial and followed everything he did. Player has 3 lives default (as you can see in Health Script bottom of page.) I want In-Game Text that show how many lives left to Player.

Firstly I created a Text and create new **LivesDisplay** script into that. Then I access Health Script (which this is Player object component) and take currentLives variable in LivesDisplay script.

**LivesDisplay script**

```
public class LivesDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Text livesText;
    int remainingLives;

    private void Start()
    {
        remainingLives = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Health>().currentLives;
        Debug.Log("Entered Start Method");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        livesText.text = "Lives : " + (remainingLives).ToString();
        Debug.Log("Entered Update Method");
    }

}
```

When I start game, default variables shown correctly as you can see.

[image: Lives Image]

When Player hit in game, this lives variable should decrease, but not happen. I already check maybe game not dive into the LivesDisplay script but when you see console everything seems normal.

[image: Console Image]

The weird thing is, this code worked yesterday perfectly, but today it's not. I also leave Health script here, maybe the problem source is here, but I did not wrote this script. I just drag-drop this script for tutorial, not change anything (except make some variables private to public.)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// This class handles the health state of a game object.
/// 
/// Implementation Notes: 2D Rigidbodies must be set to never sleep for this to interact with trigger stay damage
/// </summary>
public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Team Settings")]
    [Tooltip("The team associated with this damage")]
    public int teamId = 0;

    [Header("Health Settings")]
    [Tooltip("The default health value")]
    public int defaultHealth = 1;
    [Tooltip("The maximum health value")]
    public int maximumHealth = 1;
    [Tooltip("The current in game health value")]
    public int currentHealth = 1;
    [Tooltip("Invulnerability duration, in seconds, after taking damage")]
    public float invincibilityTime = 3f;
    [Tooltip("Whether or not this health is always invincible")]
    public bool isAlwaysInvincible = false;

    [Header("Lives settings")]
    [Tooltip("Whether or not to use lives")]
    public bool useLives = false;
    [Tooltip("Current number of lives this health has")]
    public int currentLives = 3;
    [Tooltip("The maximum number of lives this health can have")]
    public int maximumLives = 5;

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Standard unity funciton called before the first frame update
    /// Inputs:
    /// none
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        SetRespawnPoint(transform.position);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Standard Unity function called once per frame
    /// Inputs:
    /// none
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    void Update()
    {
        InvincibilityCheck();
    }

    // The specific game time when the health can be damged again
    private float timeToBecomeDamagableAgain = 0;
    // Whether or not the health is invincible
    private bool isInvincableFromDamage = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Checks against the current time and the time when the health can be damaged again.
    /// Removes invicibility if the time frame has passed
    /// Inputs:
    /// None
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    private void InvincibilityCheck()
    {
        if (timeToBecomeDamagableAgain <= Time.time)
        {
            isInvincableFromDamage = false;
        }
    }

    // The position that the health's gameobject will respawn at if lives are being used
    private Vector3 respawnPosition;
    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Changes the respawn position to a new position
    /// Inputs:
    /// Vector3 newRespawnPosition
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newRespawnPosition">The new position to respawn at</param>
    public void SetRespawnPoint(Vector3 newRespawnPosition)
    {
        respawnPosition = newRespawnPosition;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Repositions the health's game object to the respawn position and resets the health to the default value
    /// Inputs:
    /// None
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    void Respawn()
    {
        transform.position = respawnPosition;
        currentHealth = defaultHealth;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Applies damage to the health unless the health is invincible.
    /// Inputs:
    /// int damageAmount
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="damageAmount">The amount of damage to take</param>
    public void TakeDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        if (isInvincableFromDamage || isAlwaysInvincible)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (hitEffect != null)
            {
                Instantiate(hitEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation, null);
            }
            timeToBecomeDamagableAgain = Time.time + invincibilityTime;
            isInvincableFromDamage = true;
            currentHealth -= damageAmount;
            CheckDeath();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Applies healing to the health, capped out at the maximum health.
    /// Inputs:
    /// int healingAmount
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="healingAmount">How much healing to apply</param>
    public void ReceiveHealing(int healingAmount)
    {
        currentHealth += healingAmount;
        if (currentHealth > maximumHealth)
        {
            currentHealth = maximumHealth;
        }
        CheckDeath();
    }

    [Header("Effects & Polish")]
    [Tooltip("The effect to create when this health dies")]
    public GameObject deathEffect;
    [Tooltip("The effect to create when this health is damaged")]
    public GameObject hitEffect;

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Checks if the health is dead or not. If it is, true is returned, false otherwise.
    /// Calls Die() if the health is dead.
    /// Inputs:
    /// none
    /// Returns:
    /// bool
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Bool: true or false value representing if the health has died or not (true for dead)</returns>
    bool CheckDeath()
    {
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Die();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Handles the death of the health. If a death effect is set, it is created. If lives are being used, the health is respawned.
    /// If lives are not being used or the lives are 0 then the health's game object is destroyed.
    /// Inputs:
    /// none
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    public void Die()
    {
        if (deathEffect != null)
        {
            Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation, null);
        }

        if (useLives)
        {
            HandleDeathWithLives();
        }
        else
        {
            HandleDeathWithoutLives();
        }      
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Handles the death of the health when lives are being used
    /// Inputs:
    /// none
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    void HandleDeathWithLives()
    {
        currentLives -= 1;
        if (currentLives > 0)
        {
            Respawn();
        }
        else
        {
            if (gameObject.tag == "Player" && GameManager.instance != null)
            {
                GameManager.instance.GameOver();
            }
            if (gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>() != null)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().DoBeforeDestroy();
            }
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description:
    /// Handles death when lives are not being used
    /// Inputs:
    /// none
    /// Returns:
    /// void (no return)
    /// </summary>
    void HandleDeathWithoutLives()
    {
        if (gameObject.tag == "Player" && GameManager.instance != null)
        {
            GameManager.instance.GameOver();
        }
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>() != null)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().DoBeforeDestroy();
        }
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I am using Unity version 2020.2.7f1.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only check currentLives in start method which is only called once at when script start. So that value is not updating you have to check that value in update method.

Comment: I tried thousand things but not able to fix problem until you wrote, thank you so much!